# Consulta sobre multiples STRING_AGG con LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quería que me ayudaran con una consulta, tengo una consulta de pacientes que pueden o no tener correos y teléfonos, el select lo estoy haciendo con left join a estas últimas tablas, y con STRING_AGG estoy poniendo los múltiples correos y teléfonos que pueden tener, pero se duplican en algunos casos los correos.

Hay alguna forma de eliminar los resultados repetidos dentro de un STRING_AGG?

PD: En el left join lo tengo con distinct.

**EDIT 1**
No les puedo colocar todo el select(Tiene mas de una tabla, pero el problema se da con estas)

```
DECLARE
@dtdesde DATETIME = '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000',
@dthasta DATETIME = '2022-01-02 00:00:00.000'

SELECT  
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), _Cr.Correo),',' ) AS Email,
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), _Tl.Telefono),',' ) AS 'Telefono'
FROM Chat AS _C
INNER JOIN Usuarios AS _U ON _U.IdUsuario = _C.IdUsuario
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Correo), ',') Correo, IdUsuario, Activo FROM Correos
           GROUP BY Correo, IdUsuario, Activo) AS _Cr ON _Cr.IdUsuario = _U.IdUsuario AND _Cr.Activo = 1
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IdUsuario, Telefono FROM Telefonos
            GROUP BY IdUsuario, Telefono) AS _Tl ON _Tl.IdUsuario = _U.IdUsuario
WHERE 
_C.Fecha between @dtdesde and @dthasta
GROUP BY
_C.IdChat
ORDER BY _C.IdChat
```

Y el resultado es algo así, en algunos casos muestra un solo correo y en otro se repite ya sea por la cantidad de teléfonos que existe o viceversa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sería mejor que pongas acá la query que estás usando actualmente, para poder entender bien lo que estás haciendo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar en vez de un LEFT JOIN un OUTER APPLY y DENTRO agrupar y hacer el STRING_AGG aunque es algo subconsulta.

Sin estar seguro de que funcione, mas o menos asi:

```
SELECT
    _CR.Email,
    _Tl.Telefono
FROM
    Chat AS _C
    INNER JOIN Usuarios AS _U ON _U.IdUsuario = _C.IdUsuario
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT STRING_AGG ( CONVERT ( NVARCHAR ( MAX ), R.Correo ), ',' ) AS Email 
        FROM (
            SELECT _Cr.Correo
            FROM Correos AS _Cr
            WHERE _Cr.IdUsuario = _U.IdUsuario AND _Cr.Activo = 1
            GROUP BY Correo) as R
    ) AS _Cr
    OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT STRING_AGG ( CONVERT ( NVARCHAR ( MAX ), R.Telefono ), ',' ) as Telefono
        FROM (
            SELECT _Tl.Telefono as Telefono
            FROM Telefonos AS _Tl 
            WHERE _Tl.IdUsuario = _U.IdUsuario 
            GROUP BY Telefono ) as R
    ) AS _Tl 
WHERE
    _C.Fecha BETWEEN @dtdesde AND @dthasta 
ORDER BY    
  _C.IdChat
```

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias, no entendía bien como hacer la subconsulta y me ayudaste bastante